# replace HTML text with incrementing numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a bunch of text with no HTML, and I'm trying to find all replace all instances of `String` with `<span id="x">String</span>`
The catch is I'm trying to increment x every time to get a bunch of uniquely identifiable spans rather then identical ones.
I have no problem getting all instances of String, but for the life of me I can't get the increment to work. All help I can find seems to be directed towards doing the opposite of this.
Any ideas what I can do or where else to turn for help?

EDIT:
This is targeting a div with ID 'result' that contains only text.

```
    var target = "String";
    var X = //the number I was trying to increment
    var re = new RegExp(" " + target + " ","g");
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML.replace(re, '<span id="' + X + '">' + target + '</span>');
```

Comment: Show us your code.  Your question makes very little sense as-is.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you are using a regex, which is fine, but you can specify a function as the second parameter to `replace` and do your logic there.

The MDN documentation for doing this is here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

You could use something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gjrCN/2/

```
function replacer(orig, target) {
    var x = 0;
    var re = new RegExp(target, "g");
    var ret = orig.replace(re, function (match) {
        return "<span id='" + (++x) + "'>" + match + "</span>";
    });
    return ret;
}

var example = "String Stringasdf String2344 String";
var replaced = replacer(example, "String");
console.log(replaced);
```

You can change `++x` to `x++` if you want the counting to start at `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

You can pass a function to the `String.replace` method would allow you to increment a counter with each call and use that to set your ID:

```
var forReplacements = "I do like a String that's a nice long String with Strings in it";

var incrementer = (function() {
    var counter = -1;
    var fn = function(match) {
        counter++;
        return "<span id='"+counter+"'>"+match+"</span>";
    };
    fn.reset = function() {
        counter = -1;
    }
    return fn;
}());
var newString = forReplacements.replace(/String/g, incrementer )
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL4Qq/1/) to see it in action